# adding subquestions(take this as subqus1) from main questions only if he answer wrong in main question?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, python-3.x

Adding subquestions(take this as subqus1) from main questions only if he answer wrong in main question?
Add another subquestion(take this as subqus2) if he made the wrong answer in the subquestion(take this as subqus1)?

```
questions = ["sudeer have 5 apples and raju have 6 apples.Totally how many apples they both have?",]
sub_questions=["How much if 5 apples add with other 6 apples",]

sub_questions1 =["you have 5 apples and your mother gave you other 6 apples.How many apples do you have with you?",]

answer_choices = ["a)1\nb)2\nc)13\nd)11\n:",]
correct_choices = [{"b", "2"},]
answers = ["5 + 6 is 11",]


def quiz():
    score = 0
    for question, choices, sub_question, correct_choice, answer in zip(questions, answer_choices, sub_questions, correct_choices, answers):
        print(question)
        user_answer = input(choices).lower()
        if user_answer in correct_choice:
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        elif:
            print("Incorrect:", sub_question)
            print(question)
            user_answer = input(choices).lower()
            if user_answer in correct_choice:
                print("Correct")
                score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect", answer)

    print(score, "out of", len(questions), "that is", float(score / len(questions)) * 100, "%")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     quiz()




output:

   elif:
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I do overcome from this error and let me know how to answer for the above questions from the front-end with the same format(main questions and subquestions)?
Add another subquestion(take this as subqus2) if he made the wrong answer in the subquestion(take this as subqus1)?
Also, tell me how to connect to frontend with the python and angular5?
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you were really close. You just needed to modify the if-else statments. 
Like that:

```
def quiz():
  questions = ["sudeer have 5 apples and raju have 6 apples.Totally how many apples they both have?", ]
  sub_questions = ["How much if 5 apples add with other 6 apples", ]

  sub_questions1 = [
    "you have 5 apples and your mother gave you other 6 apples.How many apples do you have with you?", ]

  answer_choices = ["a)1\nb)2\nc)13\nd)11\n:", ]
  correct_choices = [{"d", "11"}, ]
  answers = ["5 + 6 is 11", ]
  score = 0
  for question, choices, sub_question, correct_choice, answer in zip(questions, answer_choices, sub_questions, correct_choices, answers):
      print(question)
      user_answer = input(choices).lower()
      print(user_answer)
      if user_answer in correct_choice:
        print("Correct")
          score += 1
          return
      elif user_answer not in correct_choice:
          print("Incorrect:", sub_question)
          user_answer = input(choices).lower()
          if user_answer in correct_choice:
              print("Correct")
              score += 1
              return
          else:
              print("Incorrect", answer)
  print(score, "out of", len(questions), "that is", float(score / len(questions)) * 100, "%")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     quiz()
```

Comment: How do we operate the same content with Django and angular?

Comment: @user10389226 I think, you need to create custom template tag which runs the functionality. Here is some information: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) I hope it will help. Can you also accept my solution if it answered your question. Thanks